# how to fetch data with RTK Query after a specific delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtk-query

I have a component that I want to delay data fetching for.

here is the code

```
import { CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import CardComponent from "../../features/card/card";
import { Post, useGetPostsListQuery } from "../../utils/slices/postsSlice";
import ErrorPage from "../../layout/notfound.component";

const Blogs = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, isError, error, refetch } = useGetPostsListQuery(undefined, {
    skip: true,
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true
  })

 
   setTimeout(() => {
      refetch().catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, 5000)
  

  console.log("error", error);

  if (isError) return <ErrorPage error={error}/>;

  return (
    <>
      {isFetching ? (
        <CircularProgress />
      ) : (
        <section className="flex flex-wrap justify-around p-4 bg-slate-100">
          {data?.posts.map((post: Post) => (
            <CardComponent post={post} key={post.id} />
          ))}
        </section>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Blogs;
```

In this code, I encountered the error 'Uncaught Error: Cannot refetch a query that has not been started yet.' My ultimate goal is to implement a skeleton loading state in my code. What is wrong, and what should I do?